# On the Besov space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, banach-spaces, besov-space

I want to prove this:

$$
C^{-1}\lambda^{s-\frac dp}\lVert u\rVert\smash{\dot B}_{p,r}^s
\,\le \, \lVert u(\lambda\cdot)\rVert_{\smash{\dot B}_{p,r}^s} \,\le\,
C\lambda^{s-\frac dp}\lVert u\rVert\smash{\dot B}_{p,r}^s.
$$

([original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy361.png))

I proved it for $\lambda = 2^k$ for every $k$ integer!

Can you help me to conclude..

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the proof on from this [lecture (Proposition 1.5.4)](https://perso.math.u-pem.fr/danchin.raphael/cours/courschine.pdf) .